# as3, flash cs4 pro for AIR - import flash.fileSystem.*

Tags: flash, air

pretty simple: my import flash.fileSystem.* statement isn't recognized, since 'fileSystem' isn't hilited in blue. code i'm trying to use (from adobe sample code):

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.fileSystem.*;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class T_2 extends MovieClip
    {
        public function T_2()
        {       
            var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("MyTextFile.txt");
            var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
            stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
            stream.writeUTFBytes("This is my text file.");
            stream.close();
        }

        function readBytes(e:Event):void 
        {
            var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            trace("position 0:", stream.position); // 0
            bytes[0] = stream.readByte();
            trace("position 1:", stream.position); // 1
            fileStream.readBytes(bytes, stream.position, 4); 
            trace("position 2:", stream.position); // 5
            stream.close();
        }

    }
}
```

causes these plus a few more similar errors:

1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: File.
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: FileStream.
1120: Access of undefined property File.
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method FileStream. 
... etc

spent 2 hrs looking for answers everywhere with no luck ... help much appreciated
ps have never written code with AIR as target, so may be something simple

Answer (score 1):

try

```
import flash.filesystem.*;
```

instead of

```
import flash.fileSystem.*;
```

Comment: it like 'filesystem'; but it doesn't recognize 'FileStream,' just File.  the error(s) i unknowingly copied from adobe is here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html

Comment: Hmm, it works for me - I was able to run your constructor without any problems, it even added a file to my Desktop. :)  What happens to the highlighting if you try to import FileStream directly, eg import flash.filesystem.FileStream; ?